# In ZSH, redirecting image file into graphic magick results in corrupt jpeg data (but not when using file path parameters)

Tags: shell, pipe, zsh, graphicsmagick

Currently in my ZSH shell.

Doing this, gives me:

```
> gm convert -compress JPEG - - < input.jpg > output.jpg
gm convert: Corrupt JPEG data: 873 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9 (/tmp/gmo1fx92).
```

However these 2 work without any problems:

```
> cat input.jpg | gm convert -compress JPEG - - > output.jpg
> gm convert -compress JPEG input.jpg output.jpg
```

What could be causing this difference?

Comment: It works fine in `bash`, so I guess it is related to `zsh`. My suspicion is that it has to do with i/o redirection in zsh, or the way Graphicsmagick deduces file formats from the first few bytes and/or the file extension. Maybe try `gm convert -compress JPEG JPEG:- - < inout.jpg > output.jpg` in order to give a heads-up about the format of the file on stdin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it didn't work. I later tried the same commands under bash, and it did work properly. So it does indeed look like it's a bug in ZSH.